# Splitting field of multivariable polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $f(t, x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb C[t, x]$ that is monic
> and cubic when regarded as a polynomial in $x$. Assume that for some
> $t_0$ the polynomial $f (t_0 , x)$ has one simple root and one double
> root. Prove that the splitting field $K$ of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb C(t)$
> has degree 6.

I saw a counterexample show this exercise is wrong
$$
f(x, t)=x^3-3t^2x-(t^4+t^2)
$$
This polynomial meet the requirement irreducible and has the root as required when $t=1$ but it discriminant $D \in \mathbb C(t)$ So its splitting field just 3 order over $\mathbb C(t)$.

I wonder if this exercise is wrong or this couterexample have problem.

Comment: Your counterexample checks out. The zeros of your polynomial are $$x_j=t(t^{1/3}\omega^j+t^{-1/3}\omega^{-j}), j=1,2,3,\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}.$$
It follows that the polynomial is irreducible, and its splitting field is $K=\Bbb{C}(t^{1/3})$ - a cubic extension. As another confirmation, its discriminant is $-27t^4(t^2-1)^2$, an obvious square in $\Bbb{C}(t)$.

Comment: I cannot guess what went wrong with the exercise for I'm largely ignorant about the theory around specializations and hence (unfortunately) also about the inverse Galois theory.

Comment: This is exercise from Artin algebra last chapter M.9(Galois theory). So this counterexample show this is wrong.